# Populating combo box in MFC dialog box

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I've added a combo box to my MFC dialog box. And I've added both a *control variable* (`m_wndImportMode`) and a *value variable* (`m_nImportMode`).

I'm able to use both variables just fine. And I can use the control variable to populate the control just fine. My problem is where is the correct location to populate my control?

If I populate the combo box before `DoDataExchange()` then my control variable has not yet been initialized. If I populate the combo box after `DoDataExchange()`, then it populates fine but the value does not get set.

```
BOOL COptionsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // If I populate my combo box here,
    // my control variable is not yet available

    // This will ultimately call DoDataExchange()
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // If I populate my combo box here,
    // DoDataExchange() has already been called and
    // so it will not have selected the correct item
    // before there were any items

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Playing with this a little more, I can see I can populate the control before calling `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` if I use `GetDlgItem()` instead of my control variable (which has not yet been initialized), and then the default item will correctly be set as I want. But doesn't the MFC framework provide for populating list controls in a dialog box and *still* using `DoDataExchange()`?

Comment: Post your code. You should be able to populate `CComboBox` using `AddString()` just fine after `OnInitDialog()`. There is nothing wrong with `DoDataExachange` mechanism and MFC framework in general.

Comment: I've used this for years and had none of your problems. I never call `DoDataExchange` directly; in the function you are populating the combo you should call `UpdateData(FALSE)` after.

Comment: @sergiol: I've never called `DoDataExchange()` directly either. But I can see in `OnInitDialog()` where `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` (where `DoDataExchange()`) is called. And I can populate the control before or after that. And I'm populating it in `OnInitDialog()`. Where do you populate it?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin: Guess I wasn't clear enough. I've fleshed out my description of the issue.

Comment: After populating your combo box, you need to call [`UpdateData(FALSE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww.aspx), to have the framework select the correct item. In case `m_nImportMode` happens to get overwritten, you need to save the value across the `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` call, restore it when it returns, and call `UpdateData(FALSE)` as a final step. `UpdateData` works both ways, initializing a dialog box with values from the C++ class, as well as storing dialog entries input by the user back into those values.

Comment: @IInspectable: But doesn't DDX already call `UpdateData`? That means it would be called twice, which is unnecessarily inefficient. Better to simply write custom code.

Comment: It increases developer efficiency, by writing consistent code, at the expense of making the code a bit less efficient. Runtime efficiency is important, but unless you are dealing with hundreds or thousands of control, I wouldn't bother. And if that is the case, you should start worrying about usability.

Comment: @IInspectable: I just used `GetDlgItem()` to get a reference to the combo box and populated it. Then I let `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` do it's thing. I really don't see any downside to this. (Do you?) The only downside is that it seems like MFC should allow for this somehow using a control variable.

Comment: About the question you asked to @IInspectable: No! It is the other way around! It is `UpdateData` that calls `DoDataExchange`, which contains the calls to `DDX_...` functions! Put a breakpoint on the relevant `DDX_` calling line, then look to the call stack, and you will immediately understand the mechanics behind!

Comment: @sergiol: I don't see where anything you said differs from what I said. And I don't see how any of what you said answers the questions on the table.

Comment: Read paying attention! You ask "doesn't DDX already call UpdateData? ". And I said **NO** and **WHY NOT**. You are not getting the full picture because you see things in the inverse sense, and that is reason you are not achieving on how to do things using Dynamic Data Exchange!

Comment: @sergiol: Calm down. I didn't say `DoDataExchange()`, I said DDX. And by that I just meant in the general sense that the logic implemented by the MFC wizards to implement dynamic data exchange would call `UpdateData()`. And I'm exactly right. And if you really understood the issue you would probably explain it to me instead of getting caught up on a semantic issue about something I fully understand and does not solve my issue. Even in my original question, I discuss the issues with invoking `DoDataExchange()` at different points. You'd see that if you were paying attention or understood it.

Comment: One more time: UpdateData calls DoDataExchange, and do DataExchange has lines with DDX_... calls. Put a break point on a DDX_... line and look to the call stack.

Comment: @sergiol: How many times must it be explained to you that I'm well aware of this? You didn't understand one thing I said in my last comment. Please stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using `GetDlgItem()` to retrieve the combo box, and then populating it before `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` is called. This works as intended.

I'm not sure what I might be doing differently if this is not an issue for anyone else.

Comment: Yes, that would work because `CDialog::OnInitDialog` calls `UpdateData(FALSE)`. But I would avoid writing code before `CDialog::OnInitDialog`. Put everything after `CDialog::OnInitDialog` and call `UpdateData(FALSE)` at the end. Also I would use `m_combo.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1, this)` instead of `GetDlgItem`, or add `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, m_combo)`

Comment: But I don't like the fact that UpdateData() would then be called twice. The code works fine, but I was expecting a way to do it the MFC way but still be able to efficiently populate my control.